# Autocomplete not working in VSCode using System.Reflection

Tags: python, revit-api

I'm using VSCode for writing my Python script for using them in Dynamo for Revit.
Everything is working fine except this completion :

```
import System
from System.Reflection import BindingFlags
```

VSCode tells me :

> Import "System.Reflection" could not be resolvedPylance

How to solve this problem please?

Comment: Hi @Mostafa
Yes, It works in a python Script Node into Dynamo but no way to get autocompletion in VScode...
Is it possible to post a picture into a comment?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps to see if it resolves your problem:

- Open the Command Palette by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` on your keyboard.
- In the Command Palette, search and select `Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window`.

Otherwise, you need to choose the exact virtual environment where you pip install all the required dependencies:

- Open the Command Palette by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` on your keyboard.
- In the Command Palette, search for `Python: Select Interpreter`.
- From here you need to choose the Python environment you want to work with.
- If you do not see the one you need, choose `Enter interpreter path...`
- Navigate to your project virtual environment folder.
- Go into "Scripts" folder and then select "python.exe" as the interpreter.
  These steps allow you to select the right python interpreter associated with the project's virtual environment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Alex Your solution does not resolve my problem.
I'm sure I've got the same interperter as the interpreter used by Dynamo